# How to upload file Dynamically through AutoIt Script in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-ide

Below are my AutoIt Script :

```
ControlFocus("Open","","Edit1")
ControlSetText("Open","","Edit1","C:\\project\\data\\data.csv")
ControlClick("Open","","Button1")
```

And Converting the file to exe which is used in the java file as below.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\project\\script\\TestAutoIt3.exe");
```

Now I have to upload 10 files,  I have two Questions here:

1. Can I pass the fileName dynamically and create exe files?
2. If I want to run this script in others system , the exe file will
   not work because the project might be in some other path. How can I
   handle this?

Thanks in Advance?

Comment: Do you want to upload files via webUI? Why not to upload files with `selenium` only?

Comment: Can you please let me know how can we do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upload file using `Selenium` + `Java` you need below code:

```
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://page.com");  // This is the page with file upload field
WebElement fileInput = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']"));
fileInput.sendKeys("C:\\Path\\To\\File.jpg");
```

Comment: Thanks Andresson, But how can we solve if my input type is button and it is opening a browse window?

Comment: Yes, it looks like `browse` or `upload` button (actually it's `<input type="file">` `HTML` element). It used to receive path to file. And you can handle it in mentioned way. Have you already tried my code?

Comment: There was a bug in the product. Now your code work like a champ. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the answer given from Andersson, So that there is no headache of maintaining autoIt Files(exe/au3). And no extra work needed if you are using your code in someone else systems.